# gnu screen - Copying text between windows

Tags: gnu-screen, copy-paste, productivity

Is it possible to paste text copied in a paste buffer to a different window with some keybinding, without having to leave the current window? I.e., instead of going to the window and doing a Ctr-a + ], giving a gnu screen command and the name of the receiving window?

Comment: Other than having the other windows reading constantly from `/tmp/screen-exchange`, I don't think so.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a *bind* to create such a keybinding in your screenrc, because there is none.

Depending on how you wanted to implement it (is it for a named screen whose name is known?), the following screen functions could be useful to you:

- `copy` ( `C-a esc` / `C-a [` ) to make your copy of the current window
- `writebuf` (`C-a >` ) to write `/tmp/screen-exchange`
- `readbuf`  ( `C-a <` ) to read in the other /tmp/screen-exchange
- `paste .` ( `C-a ]` / `C-a C-]` ) to write the paste on the other window
- `at [identifier][#|*|%] command [args ...]` to make other windows process the two former commands from the specified original window, without leaving it (through a keybind or directly at the screen commandline `C-a :` ).

Answer (score 0):

While this does not directly answer your question I strongly recommend switching from screen to tmux if possible. Tmux is screen on steroids.